# How to keep login when curl and go to any page of that website

Tags: php

```
function loginpage($loginurl, $loginset, $agent, $cookie){

    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST    =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT     =>     120, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT          =>     $agent, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT            =>    120, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    =>    true, 
        //CURLOPT_REFERER            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_POST            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER            =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        =>    $loginset, 
        CURLOPT_POST            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR        =>    $cookie, 
        //CURLOPT_COOKIE            =>    $strCookie, 
        //CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        =>    $cookie, 

    ); 
    $ch        = curl_init( $loginurl ); 
    CURL_SETOPT_ARRAY( $ch, $options );  
    $result     = curl_exec( $ch );  
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );  
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );  
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );  
    curl_close( $ch ); 
    return $result;  
} 

$username    = "myusername..."; 
$password    = "mypassword..."; 
$loginurl    = "http://up.4share.vn/?control=login"; 
$loginset    = "inputUserName=$username&inputPassword=$password"; 
$cookie        = "/uploads/4shareVN_cookie.txt" ; 
$agent        = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"; 

$loginpage = loginpage($loginurl, $loginset, $agent, $cookie);  
echo $loginpage;
```

With this code I can cURL and login with my account to: http://up.4share.vn/?control=login

My question is how I can keep login and go to another page of this website

EX: http://up.4share.vn/?control=account_info

and show it in php, someone help please.

Comment: Is `4shareVN_cookie.txt` writable?

Comment: @MihaiIorga It won't make a difference - `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` is commented out.

Comment: yes please show me some ex

Answer (score 1):

You can enable automatic cookie management for handling sessions in cUrl via cookie jar :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/where/you/want/to/store/cookie.txt');
```

Make sure directory is writable

Answer (score 0):

There are two important options with cookies when using PHP cURL:

**CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR**

> The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is
>   closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

So use it to save the cookie **set by the server respond**

**CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE**

> The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can
>   be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a
>   file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but
>   cookie handling is still enabled.

So use it to load your saved cookies.

In you example, this code works for me when I trying with the `http://up.4share.vn/?control=manager` URL after logged in successfully.

```
function loginpage($loginurl, $loginset, $agent, $cookie){

    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST    =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT     =>     120, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT          =>     $agent, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT            =>    120, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    =>    true, 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    =>    true, 
        //CURLOPT_REFERER            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_POST            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_HEADER            =>    0, 
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        =>    $loginset, 
        CURLOPT_POST            =>    1, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR        =>    $cookie, 
        //CURLOPT_COOKIE            =>    $strCookie, 
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE        =>    $cookie, 

    ); 
    $ch        = curl_init( $loginurl ); 
    CURL_SETOPT_ARRAY( $ch, $options );  
    $result     = curl_exec( $ch );  
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );  
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );  
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );  
    curl_close( $ch ); 
    return $result;  
} 

$username    = "zerog31"; 
$password    = "vnpy0966"; 
$loginurl    = "http://up.4share.vn/?control=login"; 
#$loginurl  = "http://up.4share.vn/?control=manager";

$loginset    = "inputUserName=$username&inputPassword=$password&rememberlogin=on"; 
#$loginset = "";
$cookie        = dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookiefile.txt" ; 
$agent        = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"; 

$loginpage = loginpage($loginurl, $loginset, $agent, $cookie);  
echo $loginpage;
```

After logged in successfully, change the `$loginurl` and `$loginset` to view the management web page. If you do not use the correct cookie, you will see the **login** page instead.

Comment: Hieu Le cho mình xin facebook hoặc yahoo có dc ko, mình có nhiều vấn đề về cURL mà ko ai giúp cả.

Comment: @NhatTuan Nice to talk with you! You can find my facebook in my user profile :)